# How do I save WriteableBitmap as png image with transparency

Tags: c#, save, png, windows-phone

I crop the circular area from the image for the avatar. I need to get pixels byte[] of the image and upload to the server in base64 format. Unfortunately method SaveJpeg() does not support transparency pixels outside the selected circle. I tried ImageTools library, but no other platform except WindowsPhone unable to create png image from the resulting byte[]. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps PngCs helps? https://code.google.com/p/pngcs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no platform API to do this. The ToolStack PNG library presents a lightweight solution.

http://toolstack.com/libraries/pngwriter

Answer (score 2):

This code worked for me. Before you try, make sure that your writablebitmap has a transparent background (You can check by assigning to a image controller image source). If not, make the background transparent from the controller it was coming from.

```
var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("temp.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (var ras = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite, StorageOpenOptions.None))
{
     WriteableBitmap bitmap = imageSource;
     var stream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
     byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
     await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, ras);
     encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight, 96.0, 96.0, buffer);
     await encoder.FlushAsync();
}
```

Take a look at it!