# Writeablebitmap from UIElement with transparent background (WP and Silverlight)

Tags: c#, silverlight, canvas, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Creating an Image from an `UIElement` is covered in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784297/silverlight-4-render-uielement-as-an-image).
I am however trying to make an image of an `UIElement` that has the non-filled background kept as transparent. This is currently done in my code like this (**NOT working** for transparency):

```
var imageBrush_Final = new ImageBrush
{
    ImageSource = bi,
    Stretch = Stretch.None
};
FinalCanvas.Background.Opacity = 0;
FindChildShieldCanvas_FinalCanvas(FinalCanvas, imageBrush_Final);
FinalCanvas.InvalidateArrange();
FinalCanvas.UpdateLayout();
WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap_Finals = new WriteableBitmap(FinalCanvas, null);
String tempPNG = results.Username + "My_Crest.png";
using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream imageStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(tempPNG, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isf))
    {
        await Cimbalino.Toolkit.Extensions.WriteableBitmapExtensions.SavePngAsync(writeableBitmap_Finals, imageStream);
    }
}
```

The image is created is of a `canvas` that has one shape added inside. The shape is filled with an `ImageBrush`, specifically `imageBrush_Final`. The canvas is only partially filled by the internal shape painter that has been painted with  `imageBrush_Final`. I would therefore like that the created `writeableBitmap_Finals`, is only filled with the shape and the rest is fully transparent.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this, and why is it not saved when the `UIElement`, i.e. `canvas` has set its background to `Opacity` to `0`?

Comment: why would you want to change the elements opacity to zero and render the element?

Comment: @ChiragShah I had to render the element for the constructor to work properly. The opacity I inserted was to try and force the black background to be transparent. But did not work. If you have another idea I can try let me know :)

Comment: So you are not getting transparent color in your rendered image? I guess saving it As png could be the problem. Anyway, ill try the code.

Comment: @ChiragShah no I get no transparency, it is just black. But all other colors are correct, so I did not suspect any image channel issue. Great thx!

Comment: I'm confused if you still want me to try the code.

Comment: @ChiragShah if you want to I would appreciate it. Since I do not know how to get the transparency.

Comment: Might want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153545/how-do-i-save-writeablebitmap-as-png-image-with-transparency